# How to reconnect socket using threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I have a simple server-client socket apps which are used for send/receive files. I need to cover situation when connection is lost (I am using TCPView to crash it) using treads. So, using threads is a **MUST** situation and I am not sure how to do that. Here is my code for client and server side. Thanks.

Client:

```
    public static void StartClient()
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        byte[] msg;
        try
        {
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAd, 1234);
            Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);
                Console.WriteLine("Client connected to {0}", sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Sending file...");
                msg = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\TCPIP\test_big.txt");
                byte[] msgLengthBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(msg.Length-3);
                int msgLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(msgLengthBytes, 0);
                Console.WriteLine("int: {0}", msgLength);
                Console.WriteLine("msgL size: {0}", msgLengthBytes.Length);

                //join arrays
                byte[] result = new byte[msgLengthBytes.Length + msgLength];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(msgLengthBytes, 0, result, 0, msgLengthBytes.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(msg, 3, result, msgLengthBytes.Length, msgLength);

                int bytesSent = sender.Send(result);
                Console.WriteLine("result size: {0}", result.Length);

                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sender.Close();

            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            }    
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        StartClient();
    }

Server:

public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    StartListening();
}

public static void StartListening()
{
    byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
        Socket handler = SocketInstance().Accept();
        data = null;
        //for the TCP header, get file information
        bytes = new byte[4];
        int bytesReceived = handler.Receive(bytes);

        int Lenght = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
        Console.WriteLine("msg length: " + Lenght);
        int TotalReceivedBytes = 0;

        while (TotalReceivedBytes < Lenght)
        {
            bytes = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
            TotalReceivedBytes = TotalReceivedBytes + bytesRec;
            data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes received total: " + TotalReceivedBytes);
        File.WriteAllText(outputPath, data);
        Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(outputPath) ? "File received." : "File not received.");
        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        handler.Close();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
    Console.Read();

}

private static Socket SocketInstance()
{
    IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAd, 1234);
    Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
    listener.Listen(10);
    return listener;
}
```

Comment: What should it do in the event that the connection is lost? The simplest way is to test before a send socket.Connected and if thats true, send your data. If the connection drops during the send then you willl get a socket exception which you already catch, you simply need to write some code in that catch block to handle that situation.

Comment: Handling situation means that my main thread should still work and with the new to try to connect again. I am not sure how to do that. I am new in threading. @Darth_Wardy

Comment: Hmm ok ... well the code you have at the moment appears to be all single threaded, you might learn something from reading this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx ... notice the use of methods that accept an IAsyncResult object, these are called "when the event happens" asynchronously and should not affect the main thread. It sounds like that's where you want to go with it. I would start by pulling the code out in to various BeginThis and EndThat methods in the fashion shown on the MS page.

Comment: I have done this and have an example on my home machine, shame i'm at work or I would post that as a possible answer for you.